# Getting width of picture box at class level in C# (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.KeyDown += this.Form1_KeyDown;
        }

        Canon playerIcon = new Canon(25, 15, 450, 595);

        Alien alien = new Alien(30, 30, 0, 0);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.Interval = 10;

            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            draw();
        }

        private void draw()
        {
            // Set up canvas:

            Graphics spaceInvanders;

            spaceInvanders = this.picCanvas.CreateGraphics();

            spaceInvanders.Clear(Color.Black);

            // Draw player icon (canon):

            SolidBrush playerBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            spaceInvanders.FillRectangle(playerBrush, playerIcon.getPosX(), playerIcon.getPosY(), playerIcon.getWidth(), playerIcon.getHeight());

            // Draw aliens:

            SolidBrush alienBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

            spaceInvanders.FillRectangle(alienBrush, Convert.ToSingle(alien.getPosX()), Convert.ToSingle(alien.getPosY()), alien.getWidth(), alien.getHeight());

            // Allow aliens to move:

            alien.move();
        }

        // Method used to handle the movement of the canon:

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) // Move left
            {
                playerIcon.move(1, 0, this.picCanvas.Width);
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) // Move right
            {
                playerIcon.move(2, 0, this.picCanvas.Width);
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) // Fire weapon
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is instead of passing hard coded values when I define the player icon (from the Canon class). By the way, the 3rd and 4th parameter are X and Y locations for the object. I want to pass in ((pictureBox.Height/2) -50)  and (pictureBox.Width/2) so that the player icon spawns directly in the middle and just above the bottom of the screen. The problem I am facing is that I cannot access this form data from where I am defining the objects.

Can anyone help? Is there a better way of doing this rather than hard coding the locations?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what exactly is here the problem? you could access the picturebox values and pass them into the constructor. Or if this picture box might change, you could pass the entire PictureBox reference into the constructor and handle the coordinates inside the class. So when the picturebox would change outside the class on the GUI it would also change inside the class, since you passed the reference!

Comment: The issue is that when I define the object and use the constructor I need to hard code the X and Y and I cannot just pass in the picture box width because apparently it is out of context.

Comment: Is this multi-threaded? If not, you can pass the PictureBox in the class constructor like Mong Zhu says. If it is, then you could still pass the size in the constructor.

Comment: Could you show me how? Whenever I try to pass the pictureBox into the constructor it says that I cannot do it.

Comment: Declare the Cannon class; `Canon playerIcon;`, but don't initialize it until the load event, before you start the timer.  Dangerous timer, by the way.  It also needs to be declared at the form level or else it might not get disposed properly.  You should avoid CreateGraphics — it's almost always a mistake to use it.  Use the Tick event to invalidate your panel: `picCanvas.Invalidate();`  Use the panel's paint event to get your graphic object and do your painting there.

Comment: So should I define my playerIcon object at class level or inside the load event? Thanks for feedback! :)

Comment: I have just made it and that works really well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I already answered that.  If you declare your playerIcon in the load event, how would you get access to it from the other methods?  Declare all your required objects at the form (class) level.  You can initialize them in the load event, or in the form's constructor *after* the `InitializeComponent();` call.